# How to associate a custom taxonomy to a post multiple times

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

On my Posts, I'm trying to associate a custom taxonomy to it multiple times. The example is that I have a User taxonomy and a Post which is like an event. I want to be able to associate the User taxonomies who were at an event, but also Users who led the event. This data is populated from the same source, but is just classified differently.

Comment: Terms can only be associated to a post once - not multiple times. You'll need to create duplicate terms in a second taxonomy - so, say, a "Leaders" taxonomy - in order to be able to associate some Attendees and some Leaders and differentiate between the two kinds of relationships.

Comment: Perhaps you can get around the fact that you can only associate terms from a taxonomy once by creating a custom field for the 'Leaders'. Then you can populate that custom field (select or checkboxes) with all the terms from your custom taxonomy 'Users' and in turn save it to your Post.